# value from a JSON from LogicApp

Tags: azure-logic-apps, logical-operators

I have a Value which is this kind:

```
{
  "Date": "Thu, 14 Jul 2022 09:47:15 GMT",
  "Server": "Apache",
  "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains",
  "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
  "Cache-Control": "no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0",
  "Pragma": "no-cache",
  "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
  "Location": "https://ipro.ttg.global/Webcontrols/login.html;jsessionid=0BAB4EE4AEE971DC83BFC8B18A1D13D4",
  "Set-Cookie": "JSESSIONID=0BAB4EE4AEE971DC83BFC8B18A1D13D4; Path=/Webcontrols; HttpOnly;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=strict",
  "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
  "Expires": "0",
  "Content-Length": "0"
}
```

I want only the value of jsessionid what should I do in LogicApps?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the workarounds that you can try. We could able to get your requirement by using below expression in compose connector.

```
slice(body('Parse_JSON')?['Location'],add(lastIndexOf(body('Parse_JSON')?['Location'],'='),1),length(body('Parse_JSON')?['Location']))
```

Below is my Logic App

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Below is my codeview

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@triggerBody()",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Cache-Control": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Content-Length": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Date": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Expires": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Location": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Pragma": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Server": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Set-Cookie": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Strict-Transport-Security": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "X-Content-Type-Options": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "X-Frame-Options": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "X-XSS-Protection": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "jsessionid": {
                "inputs": "@slice(body('Parse_JSON')?['Location'],add(lastIndexOf(body('Parse_JSON')?['Location'],'='),1),length(body('Parse_JSON')?['Location']))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```